# How do I create my own data type with Arrow

Tags: android, kotlin, arrow-kt

What are the steps to create my own data type when using arrow.

It's simple to use something like `Option` with the provided extension constructors like `Some(data)` or `None`. However, how can I create my own data type that has functional operators like `map()` or `flatMap()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to create data types in Arrow that conform to Type classes like `Functor` and therefore provide methods like `map` is outlined here:

1. Enable higher kinded type emulation. https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/glossary/#higher-kinds
2. Implement the type class instance
   https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/glossary/#using-higher-kinds-with-typeclasses

In the two links above there is an example that uses `ListK` wrapping the std lib `List`. What the documentation example does not mention is that in order to expand the extensions which Functor would add over ListK including `map`, `lift`, etc as defined in the `Functor` interface it requires kapt and arrow meta.

```
kapt    "io.arrow-kt:arrow-meta:$arrow_version"
```

Arrow meta is in charge of expanding Higher Kinds and Extensions for type class instances. One limitation in the current expansion is that if you plan to use both `@higherkind` and `@extension` in the same module it won't work due to the order in which kapt processes. For that you would need to have data types in one module and extensions in a different one. This is actually good practice and what we follow in Arrow because it allows user to import data types a la carte when they don't want the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly:

https://arrow-kt.io/docs/patterns/glossary/

Note that the annotation processors should be able to generate the typeclass instances for you.  But fundamentally you just need to decide which typeclasses your datatype will support and provide implementations for those typeclasses.  (Note that the typeclasses form an inheritance hierarchy so (e.g.) if you implement Monad you (may) need to implement Functor.)

Comment: Ok, this was an initial test for the tag [arrow-kt] that I created. However, a link to a glossary is not that much of an answer. As they say: Show me the code ;)